# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Puzzling's [first moderator election](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Emrakul]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/flair/20.png))</sub>
[image: Deusovi] [image: MOD3_NAME]

They'll be installed as [the moderator team](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

I personally thank [Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20), [Kevin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4/kevin) and [Doorknob](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/39/doorknob) for their sterling work during the beta. This site had particularly difficult growing pains and the *pro tempore* moderators often got stuck in very difficult positions. (I apologize for times *I* made their job harder than it could have been.) Please join me in thanking them for their efforts; the site is in a much better place today than during beta.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4856922670891008/0).

Comment: Congrats Emrakul, Deusovi, and GentlePurpleRain! I'm confident you'll all do an excellent job. :)

Comment: Thanks Emrakul, Kevin & Doorknob for getting this stack going! Congratulations Emrakul, Deusovi & GentlePurpleRain!

Comment: Congratulations for the three of you and thanks to Kevin and Doorknob. I'm excited to see where this takes us :)

Comment: Congrats Emrakul, GPR, Deusovi :D Why be a [king](http://65.media.tumblr.com/38561e397cb27a49b057ec7d92f42b00/tumblr_nwj0lxnMAd1s8njeuo1_1280.png) ,when you can be a MOD ^-^

Comment: Congrats Emrakul, Deusovi, and GentlePurpleRain. :)

Comment: Congrats to all of you! Now I just need to start hatching evil plans to make your lives more difficult, um, I mean more busy and interesting.

Comment: Congratulations again everyone!

Comment: Congratulations to Emrakul, Deusovi, and MOD3_NAME (going by the image alt text) ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations to our new moderators - Deusovi♦ , Emrakul♦♦ and GentlePurpleRain♦. Even though it is hard to break a diamond, it still should be kept with care. We hope you all will do so. We are confident that you all will lead us to make this community better with every passing <del>century</del> <del>decade</del> <del>year</del> <del>month</del> week.

Thank you to our past moderators Doorknob♦ , Emrakul♦♦ and Kevin♦ for taking this community where it stands today. It has been a pleasant journey. Thank you for listening to our childish problems and then taking the burden of solving them.

Also thank you to all the candidates who took part in this election to make this election more fun, enjoyable and interesting.

And finally thank you to all the active members of the Puzzling community who share the part of their time for creating and solving the puzzles. Without all of you, PSE wouldn't be here.

#PuzzlingIsGreat