# Thank you, GentlePurpleRain

Tags: discussion, moderators

On 29 March 2022, our own [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain) received a [Deputy badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy?userid=4421) which can only be awarded to non-moderators. Without speculating on why he stepped down (unless he wants to share his reasons), **let's thank him for everything he did as a moderator**, from [2016](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5150/5373) up to 2022.

Six years is a heck of a long period in internet terms, but GPR was active in helping the site and community even before then.

- One of his contributions that I particularly remember was [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4862/5373) which helped to turn a general rumbling feeling that we'd like to have bounties on questions, mostly expressed in chat, into a constructive format that could involve lengthily explained reasons and communication with CMs.
- GPR also created a comprehensive [archive of clues used in the Cryptic Clue Chat Chain](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOR80-CRwBbb7odMLt2QRx_uEIefjovIOjFzZ_2VqoY/edit#gid=1924270515), which is still regularly [linked in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=GPR&user=&room=14524) although it hasn't been updated for a good long while.

His lower (public) activity has been noticeable in the last couple of years, so let's take the opportunity to wish him well in all his exploits both online and offline, and hope to see him creating and solving puzzles here again now that the diamond responsibility has been lifted from his shoulders.

Comment: GPR or remaining mods, please let me know if there's anything wrong with this post. I'm happy to edit or delete it if necessary; I thought it'd be nice to give GPR a thanks and sendoff, but understand if for some reason you'd rather not have this mentioned on meta.

Comment: Indeed, GPR gently chided me early on for missteps and encouraged me later for well-meant efforts.  Yeah!